# Change color of LineSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hoping someone can help.  I've spent about 4hrs so far trying examples I've found on forums to do this to no avail.  Below is my XAML code; I would think there would a be a simple way to insert a parameter to set the color, but I've not found one that works.

I've also tried code behind; all the examples I've found do not change anything.

```
<Grid>
    <charting:Chart Name="lineChart"
                                   Title="Stock" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                   Margin="0,10,10,0" 
                                   Height="550">
        <charting:LineSeries Name="Price"
                                            Title="Price"  
                                            DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                            IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}"
                                            IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        <charting:LineSeries Name="SMA50" 
                                            Title="50 SMA"  
                                            DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                            IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}"
                                            IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        <charting:LineSeries Name="SMA200" 
                                            Title="200 SMA"  
                                            DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                            IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding [2]}"
                                            IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
    </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Here is my code that calls the window

```
private void bGraph_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Graph g = new Graph();
    g.Show();

    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listPrice = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listSMA50 = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listSMA200 = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();

    DateTime d = new DateTime(2000,1,1);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        listPrice.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i));
        listSMA50.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i*2));
        listSMA200.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i * 3));
        d = d.AddDays(1.0);
    }


    var dataSourceList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>>();
    dataSourceList.Add(listPrice);
    dataSourceList.Add(listSMA50);
    dataSourceList.Add(listSMA200);

    g.lineChart.DataContext = dataSourceList;


}
```

Any help would be awesome.  It appears to me the windows form version of charting is a lot simpler to use than the WPF version.

Comment: what library is this charting namespace from?

Comment: I'm using system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit

Comment: And from what namespace is Graph?

Comment: Graph is the name of my window.  Here is the full XAML code

Comment: <Window x:Class="StockBacktester.Graph"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
        xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        Title="Graph" Height="600" Width="900">

Comment: The class Graph in the code behind, in what namespace is he?

Comment: Ahh, chart should be lineChart which is declared in the view ok...

Answer (score 1):

You specify it with the DataPointStyle property:

```
<charting:LineSeries Name="Price"
                    Title="Price"  
                    DependentValuePath="Value" 
                    IndependentValuePath="Key"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}"
                    IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                    DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myDataPointStyle}" />
```

Which in this case I'm assuming is a static resource:

```
    <Style x:Key="myDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
```

If you need to do this dynamically and don't want to use data binding then you can of course also do it programatically:

```
var style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(LineDataPoint);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue));
this.Price.DataPointStyle = style;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark; I got the xaml example you gave me to work.  Took a bit to figure out how to stick the style in (used Window.Resources).  I couldn't get the c# code example to work; it seems like LineDataPoint belongs to the forms namespace and I'm doing a WPF example.  Is there a way to use it with my WPF program or is it only for Forms?  Thanks for the help getting me up and running; the dynamic cause would be a bonus but not critical.

Comment: Doesn't sound right, have you accidentally referenced both the forms and wpf versions of the library? I added Toolkit via NuGet, when I place the cursor over "LineDataPoint" in the source file and hit F12 the second line of the metadatafile is `// C:\a_local_folder\WPFToolkit.DataVisualization.3.5.50211.1\lib\System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll"`

Comment: I didn't add the using system.windows.controls.datavisualizaiton.charting.... did that now and it works.  Stupid omition.... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in charting but I would like to help out.

There are a few things that seem odd.

1. You are binding to a elements in the grids DataContext{Binding [0]} but it is never set.
2. You are new-ing a Graph class and trying to show it but it is not connected to the view in any way.
3. This should work in the constructor:
   (Setting the DataContext for the window because your view is binding to that)

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listPrice = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
       List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listSMA50 = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
       List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> listSMA200 = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();

       DateTime d = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

       for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
       {
           listPrice.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i));
           listSMA50.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i * 2));
           listSMA200.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(d, i * 3));
           d = d.AddDays(1.0);
       }


       var dataSourceList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>>();
       dataSourceList.Add(listPrice);
       dataSourceList.Add(listSMA50);
       dataSourceList.Add(listSMA200);

       this.DataContext = dataSourceList;

       InitializeComponent();
   }
   ```

### Update

This changes the stroke width but for some reason the color doesn't change.

```
    private void bGraph_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var style = new Style(typeof(Polyline));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Polyline.StrokeProperty, Brushes.Red));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Polyline.StrokeThicknessProperty, 5.0));

        ((LineSeries) lineChart.Series[0]).PolylineStyle = style;
        ((LineSeries) lineChart.Series[1]).PolylineStyle = style;
        ((LineSeries) lineChart.Series[2]).PolylineStyle = style;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  My app has two windows, the main window, and this window graph.  Clicking on a button in the main window bGraph_Click calls the app to open a new window.  Everything is working and the data is displayed; except that I can't seem to change the line colors of the graph.

Comment: @ErnieCooper ah sorry, are you trying to change the colors at runtime?

Comment: @ErnieCooper I can change the width but the color won't change, seems like an error in the control.